# If ID matches key ID in another table display message

Tags: php, yii

I am currently attempting to generate a form that allows users to register to an event on a page after registering.

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to prevent it from showing the same message when they have registered

My shot so far includes looking at the event attendees, grabbing the user and event ID's in eventattendee table, then matching them against the event ID from the event table

Event model :

```
public function getRegistrationLink() {

       $eventAttendees = EventAttendees::model()->findAll('user_id=:user_id', array(':user_id' => $userID));
       $eventAttendees->getEventsAttendingfor();

        // No Sessions for this event
        if ($this->getCountSessions() <= 0) {
            return self::BOOKING_STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE;
        } else if ($this->getRemainingCapacity() > 0 ) {

            return CHtml::link('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> I\'d like to attend', Yii::app()->createUrl("event/register", array("id" => $this->id)));

            //LINE I'm HAVING ISSUE WITH
            if($eventID == $eventTableID ) {

                return CHtml::link('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> You are attending. View booking details ', Yii::app()->createUrl("event/view", array("id" => $this->id)));

            }
        } 
         else {
            return self::BOOKING_STATUS_SOLD_OUT;
        }
    }
```

The line I'm having issue with is

```
if($eventID == $eventTableID ) {

                return CHtml::link('<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> You are attending. View booking details ', Yii::app()->createUrl("event/view", array("id" => $this->id)));

            }
```

I'm not sure if matching the ID's would be the best way to change this message or how I would even go about declaring the same ID but from two different models  / tables and basing this on the user ID

The table I am using is event attendees which includes the event ID and user ID and the event table which has the event ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should query the event attendees tables and add a where statement to get only rows where event ID match the event you want to check against, and where user ID match the ID of the logged in/registered user.

If the query returned one row then user is registered.

The query should be something like:

`SELECT count(*) FROM event_attendees WHERE 'event_id' = 123 AND 'user_id' = 456;`